# Why do speed sensors fail so often?

Tags: sensor, hall-effect, reliability

The typical vehicle speed sensor (variable reluctance sensor) is a very basic device which essentially amounts to a coil of wire wrapped around a permanent magnet.

Simple, yes, but very reliable? Apparently not so these days...

Years ago, I worked on some ancient airport CAT (cash-audit terminals) which would read a magnetic stripe printed on a length of a thick paper card. When the motorist provided the cashier with the card, the machine would read the stripe, calculate the parking fee and using a rather unique printing mechanism, hammer out the text of the charges onto the card as a receipt. The machines were made by a company in San Diego known as 'Electron' - they went out of business in the late 80's.

I bring up the CAT units because of their interesting printing mechanism - an electric motor would turn on, and a round metal disc (platen) with numbers and letters embossed around the perimeter was attached to the motor using a specially made rubber band. As the wheel spun, an ink wheel rolled over the characters on the outside of the wheel. As the card passed through a channel, a cantilevered solenoid with a little hammer-like head would strike - pressing the passing thick paper receipt against the spinning print wheel as a stepper motor positioned the receipt for the next character to be printed.

The timing, speed and precision were amazing - I used to fix them and marveled at how well engineered and reliable they were.

I bring that up because there was a hall-effect sensor that sensed an index mark on the spinning wheel. This signal was sent back to the circuit to adjust the timing of the stepper and hammer strikes. In the 7 years that I worked on those machines, I only recall a very rare few times when we had to replace the printer sensor - maybe less than 5 times in 7 years across about 50 units.

Just about every car I've owned has had wheel speed sensors go out. Now, based on my limited understanding of the manufacture of these items, and of their basic design, I have to wonder what could possibly go bad with a wire coil and permanent magnet encased in epoxy?

What am I missing?

Comment: Wheel speed sensors aren’t in a benign environment. Heat from brake disc, vibration and shock from the road. Water and moisture ingress. Or it could be the lead wires break from flex and vibration.

Comment: the printer was not outside, getting beat up by potholes

Comment: _"Just about every car I've owned has had wheel speed sensors go out."_ - I have never heard of this fault. Perhaps it was just bad luck, or you bought crap cars?

Comment: Must have been those primitive WSS's without the Infineon chip with a DSP to normalize and process the dynamic signals that change with gap, temperature and RPM/V over a 100:1 range . But let me know if I assumed wrong.

Comment: Well, inside a spinning car wheel is a much rougher environment that on a table under a roof. I do not think they are really comparable.

Comment: "Well, inside a spinning car wheel is a much rougher environment that on a table under a roof. I do not think they are really comparable." - No, I'm not so much concerned about the failure *rate* as I am why does a coil/magnet even in good conditions FAIL? There are no moving parts, and all else considered, it's very low voltage.

Comment: @BruceAbbott -- according to the two expert mechanics in my organization, the sensor issue visits several brands and doesn't seem to be just endemic to one brand. There does appear to be data suggesting that there are bad batches, but in reviewing how the circuits work and the devices themselves, it defies your standard QA problem. Then again, car manufacturer's know that shaving 1 penny from the cost of a part can save them more than your average salary in production costs...

Comment: Wheel speed sensors are not hall, are reluctant sense coil. They break simply because they are right on the wheel in one of the most harmful place of the car. Also, the car has to be cheap and they prosper on selling replacements!

Comment: You'd have to an autopsy of the failed sensor to tell what exactly that broke. "My speed sensor failed so it must be the hall effect IC failing" is a flawed reasoning. (Assuming it is even an hall effect sensor which I doubt.) It could be some IC, or it could be some protection diode, or the supply, or the cables/connectors, or mechanical parts, or solder joints. And so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable reluctance pickup coils are wound of fine wire, and located in an engine compartment with temperature that cycles from hot to cold.

Often they are potted which can increase forces on the wires if it is not done very carefully. That was not necessarily well understood in the early days so you'd see a lot of open coils, at least on American cars.

Edit: For more information you can read [this patent](https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/68/22/a0/5801553ef5769a/EP0571129A1.pdf) which points to the encapsulation and subsequent temperature cycling as the major source of reliability issues.

Comment: I considered thermal fatigue in a number of ways, none of which really apply outside of the usual and expected day/night cycles. Last I checked, my wheel sensors were far enough outside of the engine compartment to make it much less a factor than would vibration.

Comment: @Redgum see reference in above edit. You will also note significantly increased sophistication in the encapsulation products offered to automotive OEMs.

Comment: OK, that does explain a lot. Obviously, it's been an issue and I'm glad others have studied and tackled the problem. Now the obvious question is, with this knowledge available since 1993, why do... oh, wait... it's about money and not reliability. Silly me.  Thank you!